# Displaying vertex coordinates of a polygon on a map in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a polygon shape loaded in QGIS, and I'd like to display every vertex' coordinates on the map in a label or popup next to it, how can I do that?
[image: Sample image]

Comment: This follow-up [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/381114/84870) provides alternative solutions.

Comment: @JGH: Thank you, that was a nice and clean solution, thumbs up!

Comment: There's another follow-up question with a solution by user Taras using virtual layers: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/381247/88814

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First extract your vertices with "Extract Vertices" from processing toolbox:

[image]

Then open label properties of this Vertex layer and add an expression like `round($x,8) || ' ' || round($y,8)` as label.

[image]