# Displaying vertex coordinates of polygon or line without creating new layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, vector, coordinates, vertices

I am wondering if there is a way to display coordinates for each vertex of a polygon by only using expressions, without creating a new layer. So this question is basically inspired by [Displaying vertex coordinates of a polygon on a map in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381093/displaying-vertex-coordinates-of-a-polygon-on-a-map-in-qgis/381095#381095) and enhancing it.

I thought about creating an array containing all vertices as geometry. So I have created this expression:

```sql
array_foreach( -- Go throuth every element of the following array
    string_to_array(geom_to_wkt(nodes_to_points($geometry)),','), -- Create the array of WKT information splitted by comma [ 'MultiPoint ((0.2974026 51.8987013)', '(0.00909091 51.50… ]
        make_point( -- Create a point geometry for every array content
            to_real(if(
                length(regexp_substr( -- Only create X coordinate if
                    regexp_substr(@element,'\\d.*\\d.[0-9]'),'([^ ]+)'))>0, -- everything between the Brackets of 'MultiPoint ((0.2974026 51.8987013)' before the whitespace '0.2974026' is not empty like ''
                    to_real(regexp_substr(regexp_substr(@element,'\\d.*\\d.[0-9]'),'([^ ]+)')), -- Extract the X coordinate of 'MultiPoint ((0.2974026 51.8987013)' --> 0.2974026
                    NULL -- If invalid coordinate use NULL, maybe replace with 0
            )),
            to_real(if(
                length(regexp_substr( -- Only create Y coordinate if
                    regexp_substr(@element,'\\d.*\\d.[0-9]'),'(?<=\\s).*'))>0, --  everything between the Brackets of 'MultiPoint ((0.2974026 51.8987013)' after the whitespace '51.8987013' is not empty like ''
                    to_real(regexp_substr(regexp_substr(@element,'\\d.*\\d.[0-9]'),'(?<=\\s).*')), -- Extract the Y coordinate of 'MultiPoint ((0.2974026 51.8987013)' --> 51.8987013
                    NULL -- If invalid coordinate use NULL, maybe replace with 0
            ))
        )
)
```

Which returns an array like `[ <geometry: Point>, <geometry: Point>, <geometry: Point>, <geometry: Point>, ... ]`, which represents all the vertex of the polygon. One can easily extract X and Y coordinates out of it by adding `x()` or `y()` in front of `make_point()`, or by just adding another `array_foreach()` like `array_foreach(*expression above*,x(@element))`.

How could I use such an array to label every vertex with its coordinates? I thought of extracting them from the array, but cant iterate over it. Would this be possible? Or something similar? I am kind of stuck now...

Comment: You have only one feature (a polygon) so one label for its geometry. You can place labels at each vertices (Labels > Position > Geometry Generator (Point / Multipoints) > `nodes_to_points($geometry)`) but can't have vertex coordinates.

Comment: See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/381148/88814 and https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/381187/88814

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a way to **display** the coordinates... though not as a label.

One can add style with `geometry generator` to extract the vertices, then add a `font marker` style that will be overridden to display the vertices coordinates..

1. add the vertices

Add a style of type `geometry generator`, geometry type `point` computed with the expression `nodes_to_points( $geometry)`

[image]

2. Style it as a `Font Marker`

[image]

3. Instruct to display the coordinates

Scroll down and click the box to the right of `character(s)` to edit the data-defined override. Enter the following expression

```
round(x( geometry_n( $geometry, @geometry_part_num )),4) || ' - ' || round(y( geometry_n( $geometry, @geometry_part_num )),4)
```

Let's break it down a bit:

`geometry_n( $geometry, @geometry_part_num ))` --> get the `nth` geometry from the one being rendered. From step 1, the geometry being rendered is an array of point (each vertices). Because we use `@geometry_part_num`, it is applied on every part (= on every vertex).
`x(..)` and `y(...)` -> the x/y coordinates of the point
`round(..)` --> let's not display 18 decimals :-)
`|| ' - ' ||` --> Concatenate the X and Y coordinates, separate them with a `-`

[image]

Comment: Bravo, works perfectly!  I would add for future readers that at 3.16.1 I did not initially see the "... epsilon besides character(s).."  Instead, I saw the default button (not sure what to call it!).  However, clicking on that default button and selecting *Edit...* brought up the Expression String Builder window, into which the expression can be written.  At that point the default button displays the epsilon symbol, as circled in the answer.

Comment: Great @JGH However confusing that in QGIS, vertices are refered to differently depending on context: normally, they are called vertices. In the expression `nodes_to_points` they are refered to as nodes, whereas `geometry_part_num` names them geometry part - good to remember!

Comment: @babel Indeed! Though the `geometry_part` is more generic as it could refer to polygons or else (like a generated multiple ring buffer)

Comment: OK, so indeed geometry_part is not exclusively for vertices. 
Still, there is another name: in the expression `point_n(geometry,index)` vertices are refered to as points.

Comment: Now thats one clever trick! And works with lines as well :)

Comment: @JGH and MrXsquared : see this question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381148/qgis-expression-for-label-text-to-display-vertex-coordinates-of-polygons - maybe you find a solution to it so that the original idea of getting real labels for vertices can be achieved - I'm pretty sure that it sould be possible somehow, even though I'm stuck as to how to continue.

Comment: Very nifty ... I forgot the possibility to use marker points !

Answer (score 3):

There is still something to copy from OpenJUMP (and improve). In OpenJUMP vertex XY is available as a decoration. Unfortunately the font or the numbers is tiny and there is no user interface for changing it.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

I was reading the question too fast and used wrong decorations first.

[image]

[image]