# Permanently viewing vertex of polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, visualisation, vertices

I work with shapefiles in QGIS 3.20. I have many polygons and I need to see their vertices. How do I show the vertices on the polygons?

I have gaps between polygons shown by the topology checker. I need permanently show every vertex for snapping to other polygons.

Comment: If you just want to see them visually, take a look at @JGH's answer here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/381130/107424 (simply use another marker style)

Comment: @Taras May I suggest to add "ïn QGIS" to your question title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the green plus in the `symbology` tab of your layer properties, add a second symbology. Change that type to `border - marker line` and the placement of the markers to `every vertex`.

[image]